# Sending TX in Ethereum won't return a response

Tags: transactions, javascript, goerli, sendtransaction, sendrawtransaction

I'm trying to send ETH in goerli by this code

let

```
 provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK);
let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(prK, provider);
wallet.sendTransaction({
  to: process.env.ADMIN_WALLET_ADDR_ON_ETHEREUM,
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0001")
})
.then((x) => {
  console.log(`OK: ${x}`)
});
```

While it'll send ETH **successfully**, and it'll appear on etherscan, it'll never get to the `console.log(...)` part. That is, it'll stop and hang in the terminal indefinitely  until I break it by `Ctrl + C`.

What's the matter? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you exactly need to log, but maybe you can try assigning the transaction to a variable, use await and display it after. Something like:

```
provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK);
let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(prK, provider);

async function main () {
    let result = await wallet.sendTransaction({
        to: process.env.ADMIN_WALLET_ADDR_ON_ETHEREUM,
    console.log(result)
    })
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I Would say that this behavior (not executing the console.log) is due to you not handling errors with catch, try to add a catch statement and to console.log().

For the indefinite wait, it looks like a promise not resolving, meaning that it's in the indefinite state of pending, it is likely to be due again to the absence of catch statement : errors not being resolved.

I might be wrong on this one, feel free to correct me if you find the answer.